# vertex tcp client dropping packet

Tags: tcp, vert.x

I have created Vertx TCP Server and corresponding TCP Client. The job of the TCP client is to read logs (in gzip format) from a specific directory and continuously upload to the server. The server would then do some processing and persist the data. Because the logs are in gzip format, hence the average size of a log file is 144 KB. My TCP Client simulator is spawning 4 threads, each thread will create 100 such log files and upload them to vertex server. So at the end, I expect to see 400 (= 100 * 4) files uploaded to the server. 
But to my surprise, once the simulator finishes, I see the server has processed only 76 files and there is no sign of remaining 324 files. I have run it multiple times, but every time the server processes around 75 files.
From the TCP client log, I see that all 400 files have been uploaded. So it seems the server is dropping some packet. But from the server log, I see only ~76 files have been processed. 
Later I reduced the compressed log file size generated by the simulator to make it 8KB (each log file now has lesser number of log entries), and this time I see around 398 files are processed at server side.

Apparently it seems to be some configuration issue. Maybe I have to configure the Vertex server with more resources (instances, increase received buffer size and event queue size, etc). But how would anybody know the limit, beyond which the packets will be dropped.

1. More precisely, what are the "specific" configuration required in such case.
2. Secondly, is it possible to configure the Vertx "TCP" client/server with some acknowledgement sort of mechanism, so that the client can upload the subsequent file, only when the previously uploaded file has been processed successfully.

Comment: If the client would have dropped packets, you wouldn't see less files. You may have seen files of different sizes. What probably happens is that you close your clients too soon. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to solve this, though/